# Highlight Row if Value in Column is above 0 - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to get a Google spreadsheet to automatically highlight all rows in a spreadsheet where the value in a particular column is above 0. I have looked for a few solutions but haven't got it to work.

I have got various metrics in the columns, so say I want to highlight all rows, in which column "I" has a value of more than zero.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I'm aware of would be to write a script.

Link: [Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)

The following is not pretty, but it works:

```
function myFunction() {
  var I_INDEX = 1;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Highlight rows");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=1; i<=dataRange.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var row = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1, 2);
    if (dataValues[i-1][I_INDEX] > 0) {
      row.setBackground("red");
    }
  }
}
```

See [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmR0r1Y14zgydG03QS1Dd0dLRDA3SWgtLXp6TzV3d3c#gid=1), use "Tools" --> "Script Editor..." to view/run the script.

Comment: HI, Thanks for the response, Where in this script can I specify which column to run this script against. i.e column J...

Comment: I figured it out! Thank you very much! Legend!

Comment: Thanks! If this answered your question, please "accept" the answer - http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 8):

On the conditional formatting page choose "Custom formula is" from the list of options available and then in the text field type:

```
=$I:$I>0
```

Select your formatting options and then in the range field type the range. For example:

```
A2:Z100
```

Comment: This is a simpler answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because only to be applied to a single column there is a simpler version (that I have complicated so that text is not highlighted):

Clear formatting, select ColumnI and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... `Custom formula is` and:

```
=and(isnumber(I1),I1>0)
```

with fill of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

If to format not just the relevant cell but the entire row then change the Apply to Range (say to A1:Z1000) and add anchors (`$`s) as below:

```
=and(isnumber($I1),$I1>0)
```